# batch insert dead lock

Tags: mysql, deadlock

## Can anyone help me? Why is this deadlocked?

mysql: 8.0.22

## design tables

### Note that this is the desensitized table structure

```sql
CREATE TABLE `room_db`.`Untitled` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `member_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `priority` int NOT NULL,
  `create_time` bigint NOT NULL,
  `speak_limit` int NOT NULL,
  `rorg_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `member_index` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `index_roomID_userID`(`room_id`, `member_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `idx_member_id`(`member_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `idx_room_id_create_time`(`room_id`, `create_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 3080387 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_bin ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;
```

## dead lock

```sql
Per second averages calculated from the last 43 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 4863 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 45 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 239
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 328
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 0.00 RW-shared, 0.00 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-11-25 16:18:31 139989348251392
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 20692, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1461, OS thread handle 139989752997632, query id 42017 36.156.143.18 root update
INSERT IGNORE INTO `t_room_member` (`room_id`, `member_id`, `priority`, `create_time`, `speak_limit`, `rorg_id`, `member_index`) VALUES 
('R80513', '70228779', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228780', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228781', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228782', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228783', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228784', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228785', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228786', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228787', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228788', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228789', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228790', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228791', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80513', '70228792', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 6 page no 49 n bits 296 index PRIMARY of table `room_db`.`t_room_member` trx id 20692 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6 page no 49 n bits 296 index PRIMARY of table `room_db`.`t_room_member` trx id 20692 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 20693, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1462, OS thread handle 139989220321024, query id 42018 36.156.143.18 root update
INSERT IGNORE INTO `t_room_member` (`room_id`, `member_id`, `priority`, `create_time`, `speak_limit`, `rorg_id`, `member_index`) VALUES 
('R80516', '1000228622', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228623', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228624', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228625', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228626', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228627', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228628', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228629', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228630', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228631', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228632', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228633', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228634', 20, 1700837916, 0, 'O19172', 0),
('R80516', '1000228635', 20, 170083

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 6 page no 49 n bits 296 index PRIMARY of table `room_db`.`t_room_member` trx id 20693 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6 page no 49 n bits 296 index PRIMARY of table `room_db`.`t_room_member` trx id 20693 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
```

Comment: You should tag the version of MySQL that you're using.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE t_room_member`

Comment: Mysql version: 8.0.22

Comment: @RickJames I've offered desensitization before. I just put the original table structure inside the article

Comment: Are all of the "room_id" values the same for each Insert?

Comment: What's the trx_isolation mode? Wild guess RR. If so could be related to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98324 (I think)

Comment: trx_isolation is RR. `room_id` May be duplicated due to operational impact

Comment: @jerichorivera I don't see a clear solution in the article . I need to think differently and try my business? Isn't this a bug?

Comment: I've seen frequent deadlocks when multiple sessions are inserting into a table with a PRIMARY KEY and secondary UNIQUE KEY. To solve this, you could restructure the table, remove the `id` column, and make your pair of columns (`room_id`, `member_id`) the PRIMARY KEY instead.

Comment: Another solution is to force atomic locking by using `LOCK TABLES WRITE Untitled` before the insert. Make sure to unlock as promptly as possible, because this will cause inserts to be queued.